# After setting variable value, it prints as unchanged

Tags: ios, swift, null, counter

I change the value of a variable with this function:

```
func scoreDisplay(score:Double) {
    print(score)
    CounterView().counter = Int(score)
    print(CounterView().counter)
}
```

This changes the value of `counter` in my `CounterView` class.  That class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CounterView: UIView {

    let possiblePoints = 100
    let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

    var counter: Int = 20
    @IBInspectable var outlineColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    @IBInspectable var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // 1
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

        // 2
        let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)

        // 3
        let arcWidth: CGFloat = 76

        // 4
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 4
        let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 4

        // 5
        var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)

        // 6
        path.lineWidth = arcWidth
        counterColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()

        //Draw the outline

        //1 - first calculate the difference between the two angles
        //ensuring it is positive
        let angleDifference: CGFloat = 2 * π - startAngle + endAngle

        //then calculate the arc for each single glass
        let arcLengthPerPoint = angleDifference / CGFloat(possiblePoints)

        //then multiply out by the actual glasses drunk
        let outlineEndAngle = arcLengthPerPoint * CGFloat(counter) + startAngle

        //2 - draw the outer arc
        var outlinePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: bounds.width/2 - 2.5,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: outlineEndAngle,
            clockwise: true)

        //3 - draw the inner arc
        outlinePath.addArcWithCenter(center,
            radius: bounds.width/2 - arcWidth + 2.5,
            startAngle: outlineEndAngle,
            endAngle: startAngle,
            clockwise: false)

        //4 - close the path
        outlinePath.closePath()

        outlineColor.setStroke()
        outlinePath.lineWidth = 5.0
        outlinePath.stroke()
    }
}
```

The score is being passed in properly, and prints the correct value - the problem is that as soon as I change the value of `CounterView().counter` I try to print it out, but it returns as `20` even though I just set the value to a different number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple.

You create a new instance of `CounterView` every time you write

```
CounterView()
```

So, with your code

```
CounterView().counter = Int(score)
print(CounterView().counter)
```

you have created 2 instances of `CounterView`. The `print` function is called on the newly created `CounterView` so its `counter` value is the default value you set in the implementation: `20`. You need to store the instance in a local variable. For example, your method could look like this

```
func scoreDisplay(score:Double) {
    print(score)
    let counterView = CounterView()
    counterView.counter = Int(score)
    print(counterView.counter)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can change the default value `20` to reflect the value I want.  I'm only printing `CounterView().counter` to test that the value changed, I want to change the value within the `CounterView` class.

Comment: Yes, and that way is by creating and storing an instance of CounterView. Just try the code I wrote in the end of my answer ;)

Comment: Ah yes, that returns the correct value.  However, the pie chart that is generated from `counter` remains at 20, how would I update that to reflect the value of the new instance?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by that. Maybe, you could get it done with `counter.setNeedsDisplay()` after changing its value (since I see that it's a subclass of `UIView`)

Comment: I'm glad to help you but it'd help me too if you could select my answer as the correct one (since I believe I resolved your question).

Comment: So the value of `counter` in the original instance of  `CounterView()` is 20, and the chart is generated from that number.  When I create a new instance of  `CounterView()` I want the chart in the view to reflect the value of  `counter` in the new instance of `CounterView()`, but it remains at the original value of 20.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94740/discussion-between-teldridge11-and-ajpallares).

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
CounterView().counter
```

creates a new instance of `CounterView` each time it's called.

You should create one instance, save it in a variable and access `counter` from that instance.